# Can't establish connection between React JS & Django Channels

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, websocket, django-channels

I have a web app using Django Rest Framework and React. I am trying to add web sockets to it. I opted for Django channels as they are the most recommended.

However, I keep getting this error **Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:3000/ws/canvas_data** & then the socket is closed automatically.
Apparently, the connexion can not be maintained between the frontend & the backend. I tried several options in the Routing URLs but nothing worked.
Maybe the problem is in the port since the same is used by HTTP & ws.

This is my first time dealing with Django Channels so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

This is the consumer:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer, AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from time import sleep
import json

class WSConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        print("CONNECTION IS NOW OPEN !!")
        await self.accept()
        for i in range(20):      #The logic should be here, this is just an example to test
            await self.send(json.dumps({"nom_rapport": "pv"}))
            sleep(1)

    async def disconnect(self, message):
        print("CONNECTION IS NOW CLOSED !!")
        pass
```

the asgi.py configuration:

```
import os

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import path
from Dashboard.consumers import WSConsumer

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Dashboard_sise.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': URLRouter([
        path(r'ws/canvas_data/', WSConsumer.as_asgi()),
    ])
})
```

settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     .....

    'channels',
    'rest_framework',

     .....
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Dashboard_sise.wsgi.application'

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'Dashboard_sise.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": ['redis://localhost:6379']
        }
    },
}
```

The WebSocket is declared like this:

```
 componentDidMount(){

        var socketPath = 'ws://localhost:3000/ws/canvas_data';

        const Socket = new WebSocket(socketPath);

        Socket.onopen = () => {
        console.log('Socket is connected');
        }

        Socket.onmessage = (e) => { //Logic will be placed here

            console.log("MESSAGE :", e.data);
            this.setState({messages: e.data});
        };

        Socket.onclose = (e) => {
            console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
        };
    }
```

The front end is running on port 3000, while the back is on port 8000.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what command you are using to run server?

Comment: I run the server using the  **python manage.py runserver** command.

Comment: Thanks for the link,  I'll check it out

Comment: you need to run daphne

Comment: Ahh I didn't know that, thank you so much I'll try it

Comment: Finally I have an update, your suggestions works. All I needed was to change the port to 8000 in the SocketPath and start the server using  daphne ... Thank you so much

Comment: cool, I am writing a formal answer, please accept and upvote

Comment: Alright, it's done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start a server that supports sockets like [`daphne`](https://github.com/django/daphne)

```
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 django_project.asgi:application
```